# Libgdx Loading font looking for .png while i filled in .fnt

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I got a weird problem. My code looks for data/whitetext.png wich doesnt exist so ends up in an error. But my code looks like this:

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/whitetext.fnt"), false);
```

whitetext.fnt exists in that folder. But the error I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/whitetext.png
```

Why does it look for a .PNG file and not my .FNT file?

Maybe this is the problem. I found this in another stackoverflow post:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
```

Is there a way to make this like FontBatch? (doesn't exist)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a `BitmapFont` consists out of two files: a **.png** file with the letters and a **.fnt** file with the location of those letters in the **.png**.

You also have to place the accompanying PNG file next to the FNT file for it to work. Normally generators place both of these files next to each other so you might want to check the place you originally generated the `BitmapFont` at to see whether the PNG file is there, then just grab it and place it next to your FNT file, or just simply re-generate the BitmapFont and make sure to grab both files.

Comment: Thanks yeah I forgot the .png file

Comment: also do you know how to change the font size? Its huge at the moment. Im drawing it like this:  font.draw(batch, "some string", 10, 10); adding ,64 ,64 after 10,10, doesnt work and prints nothing.

Comment: @Stefan You might want to check out the [BitmapFont API here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) you might find the `setScale` methods to be what you need. You could also read through [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672982/libgdx-how-do-i-scale-a-bitmapfont-to-changing-screen-sizes) which deals with scaling fonts based on varying resolution.